Не работает нейрсеть на Python с библиотекой sklearn и Numpy
Мой школьный проект это нейросеть, способная распознавать цифры которые я рисую в paint, а затем загружаю в код. Проблема в том что когда я загружаю абсолютно любое изображение то всегда выдает символ 2. Подскажите как исправить, я уже другие библиотеки попробовал но в основном они не поддерживаются на моем ПК.Подскажите, что можно исправить, пожалуйста! На всякий случай напишу, что из рабочих библиотек только эти, так как Pytorch и TensorFlow у меня не скачиваются(как я понял, мой ПК их тоже не поддерживает)
import os
import numpy as np
import struct
import gzip
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Функция загрузки изображений
def load_images(filename, limit=None, new_size=(28, 28)):
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        _, size, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", f.read(16))
        images = np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8)
        if limit:
            images = images[:limit * rows * cols]
        images = images.reshape((limit or size, rows, cols))
        resized_images = [
            np.array(Image.fromarray(image).resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS))
            for image in images
        ]
        return np.array(resized_images).reshape((limit or size, -1))

# Функция загрузки меток
def load_labels(filename, limit=None):
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        _, size = struct.unpack(">II", f.read(8))
        labels = np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8)
        return labels[:limit] if limit else labels

# Функция предобработки нового изображения
def preprocess_image(image_path, size=(28, 28)):
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
    image = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image).enhance(2)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.LANCZOS)
    return np.array(image).reshape(1, -1) / 255.0

# Загрузка данных
data_dir = r'C:\Work(Standart)\Personal Project\dataBase\gzip'
limit = 15000
X_train = load_images(os.path.join(data_dir, 'emnist-digits-train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'), limit=limit)
y_train = load_labels(os.path.join(data_dir, 'emnist-digits-train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'), limit=limit)
X_test = load_images(os.path.join(data_dir, 'emnist-digits-test-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'))
y_test = load_labels(os.path.join(data_dir, 'emnist-digits-test-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'))

# Разделение данных
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Стандартизация
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=97)
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val = pca.transform(X_val)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)

# Обучение модели с ядром 'rbf'
model = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1.0, max_iter=1000)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Оценка на валидационных данных
y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)
val_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_val, y_val_pred)
print(f'Validation accuracy: {val_accuracy}')

# Оценка на тестовых данных
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
test_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_accuracy}')

# Пример использования модели
image_path = r"C:\Work(Standart)\Personal Project\testImages\TestSymbol4.png"
preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image_path)
scaled_image = scaler.transform(preprocessed_image)
pca_transformed_image = pca.transform(scaled_image)
predicted_label = model.predict(pca_transformed_image)

print(f"Predicted symbol: {predicted_label[0]}")

# Проверка прогнозов на тестовых данных
test_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(f'Predicted labels for test data: {test_predictions[:10]}')
print(f'Actual labels for test data: {y_test[:10]}')



Ну вы хоть вывод то который ваш код показывает покажите в вопросе. А вообще методика какая-то древняя. Без CNN вы на картинках вряд ли хороших показателей добьётесь. Нужен Keras. А так то вангую, что у вас модель ничему не научилась, но почему-то в тренировочных данных получилось больше цифр 2, чем других (из-за limit?), поэтому она чисто вероятностно предсказывает всегда 2. Это всё нужно проверять. Хотя бы распределение y_train посмотрите.
